# Add special characters to Asp.net RegularExpressionValidator for E-Mail

Tags: asp.net, email, validation

I have a e-mail address validator but I need to add special characters as valid for example ü, ç... Because users in Turkey (or anywhere else) can have a web site url like: hasangürsoy.com My code is below:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="tEMail" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEMail" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="tEMail" ErrorMessage="* required" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEMail" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="tEMail" ErrorMessage="* invalid"
    ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" />
```

Comment: Okay I've rewriten the expression like this: \w+[\wçığöşü]+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+[\wçığöşü]+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)* the only problem is the e-mail address and domain should start with normal character (not çığöşü). If I solve this problem the work will be done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I did it. But be careful, if you use this e-mail validation expression the mail address can't pass validation when you try to use it for example ReplyTo address.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEMail" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="tEMail" ErrorMessage="* invalid" Display="Dynamic"
    ValidationExpression="\w*[\wçığöşü]+([-+.']\w+)*@\w*[\wçığöşü]+([-.]\w+)
    *\.\w+([-.]\w+)*" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\w+([ü,ç,other characters here][-+.']\w+)*@\w+([ü,ç,,other characters here][-.]\w+)*\.\w+([ü,ç,,other characters here][-.]\w+)*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the special format "\u00fc" to specify the hex value of the char. Look at the table here http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: Could you please explain how to use this in the expression?

Comment: Like any other backslash operator like \. (dot character)

[\.\u00fc\u00e7]+