# Internet e-mail validation expression validates everything

Tags: asp.net, regex

I'm validating input in a asp.net page but the problem is it validates e-mails like hasangürsoy@şşıı.com

My code is:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(email, @"\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"))
{ valid }
else { invalid }
```

**EDIT:**
I've written a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538040/add-special-characters-to-asp-net-regularexpressionvalidator-for-e-mail) before especially to validate e-mail addresses including Turkish characters but now I don't want users to be able to input mails with Turkish characters because users mostly type Turkish characters by mistake and I cannot send mails to these addresses.

Comment: Why exactly is that a problem?

Comment: It should validate that address. It's perfectly legal.

Comment: But it did not validate before. It's strange that it validates now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just use build-in [`System.Net.Mail.MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) class for email validation?

```
bool isValidEmail = false;
try
{
    var email = new MailAddress("hasangürsoy@şşıı.com");
    isValidEmail = true;
{
catch (FormatException x)
{
    // gets "An invalid character was found in the mail header: '.'."
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[RFC3692](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3696.txt) goes into great detail about how to properly validate e-mail addresses, which currently only correctly handle ASCII characters.  However this is due to change, and hence your validation should be as relaxed as possible.

I would likely use an expression such as:

```
.+@.+
```

which would ensure you're not turning people away because your regular expression gives them no choice.

If the e-mail is important you should be following it up with verification usually done via sending an e-mail to the supplied address containing a link.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you reading this:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/Valid_Email_Addresses.aspx